# Looping through column of table with jquery to push to Google App Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

I'm really stuck at creating a loop to get the 1st column data of a table with jquery. The table has the following structure:

```
<table id="table">
<tbody id="tbody">
  <tr id="tr1">
   <td id="td1_1"><input id="td1_1_number" type="number" /></td>
   <td id="td1_2"><input id="td1_2_number" type="number" /></td>
   <td id="td1_3"><input id="td1_3_number" type="number" /></td>
   <td id="td1_4"><input id="td1_4_number" type="number" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr2">
   <td id="td2_1"><input id="td2_1_number" type="number" /></td>
   <td id="td2_2"><input id="td2_2_number" type="number" /></td>
   <td id="td2_3"><input id="td2_3_number" type="number" /></td>
   <td id="td2_4"><input id="td2_4_number" type="number" /></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

At the moment I'm reading each of them individually but there are a lot of td elements in the table. The code I'm using atm is the following:

```
var data ={
td1_1_number:  $("#td1_1_number").val(),
td1_2_number:  $("#td1_2_number").val(),
td1_3_number:  $("#td1_3_number").val(),
td1_4_number:  $("#td1_4_number").val(),
td2_1_number:  $("#td2_1_number").val(),
td2_2_number:  $("#td2_2_number").val(),
td2_3_number:  $("#td2_3_number").val(),
td2_4_number:  $("#td2_4_number").val()    
}
```

I tried to use each method but got stuck because I need this array structure to be intact for pushing the data with GAS.

The data I'm appending in gs:

```
 sheet.appendRow([data.td1_1_number, data.td1_2_number, data.td1_3_number, data.td1_4_number, data.td2_1_number, data.td2_2_number, data.td2_3_number, data.td2_4_number])
```

I really would like to change to a loop approach since mine is not very elegant.

Comment: Small side question.  Why are you calling them `td#_#_checkbox` when they are number fields (type="number")?  Edit: Also your example usage is invalid as `val()` is a method and you are missing your `()`.

Comment: you are completely right I forgot the () and the name is really number. I also do have checkbox but it would come to the same result. Thank you for the hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of using the reduce method to create the object from all the inputs.

```js
           //get an array of all the input elements and reduce them to a single object
var result = $('#tbody td input').get().reduce(function(data, checkbox){
  data[ checkbox.id ] = checkbox.value;
  //return our modified data reduction
  return data;
}, {});

//show the result
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr id="tr1">
      <td id="td1_1"><input id="td1_1_number" type="number" value="1" /></td>
      <td id="td1_2"><input id="td1_2_number" type="number" value="2" /></td>
      <td id="td1_3"><input id="td1_3_number" type="number" value="3" /></td>
      <td id="td1_4"><input id="td1_4_number" type="number" value="4" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr2">
      <td id="td2_1"><input id="td2_1_number" type="number" value="99" /></td>
      <td id="td2_2"><input id="td2_2_number" type="number" value="98" /></td>
      <td id="td2_3"><input id="td2_3_number" type="number" value="97" /></td>
      <td id="td2_4"><input id="td2_4_number" type="number" value="96" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That's it! I was exactly looking for this. Thank you for taking the time to answer!